# unix match multiple patterns return success

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk, grep

Is there an easy way to search a file for multiple patterns and return success only if both patterns are found.

For example if I had a file:

```
itemA
itemB
itemC
itemD
```

I want to print the name of all txt files that have both "itemA" and "itemD"

something like:

```
find . -name "*.txt" | xargs -n 1 -I {} sh -c "grep 'itemA AND itemB' && echo {}"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
awk '/ItemA/{f1=1} /ItemB/{f2=1} END{ exit (f1 && f2 ? 0 : 1) }' file
```

Answer (score 3):

```
find . -name "*.txt" -exec grep -l 'itemA' {} + | xargs grep -l 'itemB'
```

Add `-Z` to grep and `-0` to xargs if you want to be extra careful with special characters.

Comment: +1 for concision. OSX users: Use `--null` instead of `-Z` with `grep`.

Answer (score 1):

Translating your pseudo-code into real:

```
find . -name "*.txt" | xargs -n 1 -I {} sh -c "grep -q itemA {} && grep -q itemD {} && echo {}"
```

You could shorten this somewhat by making the second `grep` print the filename:

```
find . -name "*.txt" | xargs -n 1 -I {} sh -c "grep -q itemA {} && grep -l itemD {}"
```